# My Text Is Somehow Covering My Button In Unity, I Can't Click The Button Unless I Avoid Clicking The Text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button

When I want to click my button (TextMeshPro) I can click the button, but I cant have my cursor directly on top of the text.

[Here is my button interactability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFsIf.jpg)

[Yet my button is not highlighted when I have my cursor over it (cursor disappears in a screen snip)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V35Kr.jpg)

I am setting a different GameObject to active, but when I hover the cursor over the button, there is not highlighted area.

Comment: Could you share how does button and text are layed out in your hierarchy and also their inspector settings ? You can also disable your text component's raycast target tick so it won't capture clicks.

Comment: Move the button to the top of the hierarchy

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Judah! I recommend you to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question and ease to other users to help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why it wasn't working! In order to create my options button, (a seperate button) I copied and pasted the play button, and I had not written a  code for options, so I was clicking the options button which had no action. The options button was on top of the play button. Sorry, I should have looked farther into it.